# Selecting a new dataframe via a multi-indexed frame in Pandas using index names

Tags: python, pandas

The following extract from a dataferame (at the bottom) has a multi-index with region and Quardate as the index, I want to get a new dataframe with the same index and Only the row with the max date per region.. I can't figure out how to access the dataframe index values. 
I want something like:

```
most_recent_date=totRegscore.region.Quradate.max()
```

Which just tells me 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'region'
I'll also want to do:

```
last_quarter = most_recent_date - relativedelta(months=3)
```

and the do something like:

```
quarter_score_diff = [most_recent_date, last_quarter].diff()
```

This a variant of an answer here that I can't get working... [Summary calculations on a Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736144/summary-calculations-on-a-pandas-dataframe)
Sample input:

```
                                                              Score1      Score2  
region                                           Quradate           
North_Central-Birmingham-Tuscaloosa-Anniston 2010-01-15             47           50
                                             2010-04-15             45           60
                                             2010-07-15             45           40
```

I think at this point my main issue is not being able to select the specific rows of the muti-indexed dataframe using index names....
So upon getting one dF with just current date and one with just last quarter's date the diff of the two dataframes would look like
Sample output:

```
                                                                      Score1      Score2  
              region                                        Quradate           
quarterly_diff North_Central-Birmingham-Tuscaloosa-Anniston 2010-07-15     7           6
quarterly_diff Huntsville                                   2010-07-15     6           5
```

Comment: may be it's just me, but it'll be much easier to create working solution if you add sample input and sample desired output

Comment: Edited question to clarify input and output (I hope)

Comment: what would help is showing some code which generates the exact dataframe that you are starting with, this just looks like you need to use ``xs``, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#cross-section-with-hierarchical-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I mean by showing a generating function. This creates sample data like yours, and presents and answer; now it is easy for you to say, hey I want this (and create an example output).

```
In [40]: df = DataFrame({ 'Score1' : [ 47,45,45,37,35,35], 
                          'Score2' : [50,60,40,50,60,40] },
              index=MultiIndex.from_tuples([ (r,t) for t in date_range('2010-1-1',periods=3,freq='QS')+pd.offsets.Day(14) 
                for r in ['R1','R2'] ], names=['region','date'])).sortlevel()

In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
                   Score1  Score2
region date                      
R1     2010-01-15      47      50
       2010-04-15      45      40
       2010-07-15      35      60
R2     2010-01-15      45      60
       2010-04-15      37      50
       2010-07-15      35      40
```

I find this helpful to see what is actually passed to the apply, which in this case is a frame

```
In [5]: def f(x):
   ...:     print x
   ...:     return x
   ...: 

In [6]: df.groupby(level='region').apply(f)
                   Score1  Score2
region date                      
R1     2010-01-15      47      50
       2010-04-15      45      40
       2010-07-15      35      60
                   Score1  Score2
region date                      
R2     2010-01-15      45      60
       2010-04-15      37      50
       2010-07-15      35      40
Out[6]: 
                   Score1  Score2
region date                      
R1     2010-01-15      47      50
       2010-04-15      45      40
       2010-07-15      35      60
R2     2010-01-15      45      60
       2010-04-15      37      50
       2010-07-15      35      40
```

For each region, show me the column-wise diff from 2 periods ago, among the scores

```
In [16]: df.groupby(level='region').apply(lambda x: x.diff(2))
Out[16]: 
                   Score1  Score2
region date                      
R1     2010-01-15     NaN     NaN
       2010-04-15     NaN     NaN
       2010-07-15     -12      10
R2     2010-01-15     NaN     NaN
       2010-04-15     NaN     NaN
       2010-07-15     -10     -20
```

Diff from 2 qtrs ago, just return me the last value

```
In [17]: df.groupby(level='region').apply(lambda x: x.diff(2).iloc[-1])
Out[17]: 
        Score1  Score2
region                
R1         -12      10
R2         -10     -20
```

Comment: What I'm trying to create is R1 diff from prior quarter followed by R2 diff from prior quarter. eg in your example solution, just the last line in each region. I don't get how the lambda knows to go one back for the diff, I also need one to go back 3 for the diff to get the diff from a year ago... so would that be (lambda x: x[-3].diff()) ?? so this gives me the last row only totRegscore.groupby(level='region').apply(lambda x: x.diff()[-1:])

Comment: FWIW the index for just the last row can be like : totRegscore.groupby(level='region').apply(lambda x: x.diff(4)[-1:])

Comment: @Jeff: How would you retain the date of the last row?

Comment: @unutbu the date is there at least when I run it in his form as well as when I just use [-1:] I do get the region labels duplicated in a spurious column though.. the original example was created via a prior groupby region and date..

Comment: @dartdog: To get rid of the duplicated index, try: `df.groupby(level='region', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.diff(4)[-1:])`.

Comment: ``[-1]`` will select the element (e.g. eliminate the date), while ``[-1:]`` will retain the date, depends on what you need/want